# I am not able to implement the edit code in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I am very new on starting a asp.net mvc project on my own. I am done with create work but i am stucked on edit work

This is my DAL Code

```
public class DonationContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<DonorModel> DonorModel { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller code

```
private DonationContext dc = new DonationContext();
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        dc.DonorModel.Add(donorModel);
        dc.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(donorModel);
}
```

Comment: You can use `Attach` and/or `EntityState.Modified` to update from `DbContext`, but make sure that the entity members you want to push into are already updated first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to either [attach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_2) it or set [EntityStates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_3) for it to work. I've also seen some cases where you need to turn off EntityFramework's Validation, but you'd probably notice if that's the case.

Generally, as long as your DbContext is working as intended (if you're unsure, set up a debugger and go through it right now), what you got *should* work, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `[HttpPost]` Edit like this below code. Currently, you are adding the data into database. So, to update the record, you need to either use `Attach` or `EntityStates`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(DonorModel donorModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        dc.Entry(donorModel).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        dc.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(donorModel);
}
```